# Override MuiSelect class using sx prop

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

Using material-ui's `Select` component. I'm trying to style the text I return in the `renderValue` prop. You can find my code below:

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-2885w6?file=/demo.js

When I look at the DOM, it looks like I should override the `.MuiSelect-root` class, but was wondering how to do this. I tried using the `sx` prop, but couldn't get it working.

Comment: Your code sandbox is using v4 of MUI (`@material-ui/core`). The `sx` prop was added in v5 (`@mui/material`).

Comment: @RyanCogswell Oh that's embarrassing. I'm using v4, so I guess I'll just stick to using `makeStyles` and overriding there.